# How do I fix an inline event listener that is activating when it isn't supposed to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

So, I have a block of code that is responsible for navigating through the website. I'm using React to render the JSX. I have an inline onClick event listener on the h1 tag that triggers when I click the link to navigate to my login page, when I only want it to trigger when I click the h1 element. Consequently, it then triggers the event to go back to the homepage, preventing me from moving through the site.

I've already tried taking the Link out of the nav element hoping that it would separate it more. I've also tried moving the h1 element to the bottom of the render function to get the logo at the bottom of the screen to see if the distance is the issue. I don't believe it is because I've examined it using Google DevTools and the box surrounding the h1 element doesn't overlap or even touch the Link. I noticed I get quickly redirected to home after the sign in page loads for a flash, so I'm wondering if it might have something to do with the page load. It also doesn't work when clicking other links away from the logo.

Here is the code:

```
<nav className="nav-bar">
  <h1 className="site-logo" onClick={window.location.href="/"}>DG</h1>
  <Link to="/signup" className="sign-in-link">
    Sign up
  </Link>
</nav>
```

I would like to be able to go through all nav Links and not return home unless I click the "DG", or the h1 element, instead of getting booted back to the landing page automatically. Might be an easy question to answer, but I'm relatively new to React, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use this: `onClick={() => { window.location.href = "/"; }}`, onClick expect a function not value.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a mistake here, `onClick` is an event listener so, it is expecting a callback but here you have used statement so, this can be resolved by passing a callback function to onClick like below,

```
onClick={() => window.location.href = "/"}
```